# Как добавить в AndroidStudio горизонтальные линии разделения кода?

Tags: android-studio

Как сделать в студии горизонтальные разделители как вот в [этом видео](https://goo.gl/65Rdbo)
на минуте 6.55

Там каждый метод отделен горизонтальной линеей... Мне кажется это очень удобно.

Кто знает как это включить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show method separators - поставить галочку

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень удобно теперь стало...